# complex sub query and join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to find the job title of the manager of the department with the most number of active employees in the employees database here's its structure[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5U34.png)

```
SELECT title ,dept_name
FROM titles 
JOIN dept_manager as j ON titles.emp_no = j.emp_no
JOIN (SELECT y.dept_no,EmployeeCount FROM departments as y JOIN ( SELECT 
count(*) as EmployeeCount, dept_no FROM dept_emp WHERE to_date = '9999-01-
01' GROUP BY dept_no ORDER BY EmployeeCount Desc Limit 1) AS n ON y.dept_no 
= n.dept_no )
AS s  ON j.dept_no = s.dept_no limit 1;
```

this must be the query to find it according to it but its not working i am getting to confused plese help me

Comment: Nobody will solve the task for you. I'd recommend you trying to separate the whole task by sub-tasks and moving forward to get everything correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want the number of employees in each department:

```
select de.dept_name, count(*)
from dept_emp de
where de.to_date = '9999-01-01'
group by de.dept_name;
```

Then, `order by count(*) desc limit 1` gets the department with the most employees.  Note:  you don't specify what to do with ties, so this just gets an arbitrary department with the most employees, if there are ties.

You can easily extend this by joining in `dept_manager` and `titles`.  That is how I would recommend doing this.

Comment: this is what i was trying to do but its getting to complex

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title,dept_name
from departments as k
join (
SELECT title ,j.dept_no
FROM titles as a
JOIN dept_manager as j ON a.emp_no = j.emp_no
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as EmployeeCount, dept_no 
    FROM dept_emp WHERE to_date = '9999-01-01' 
    GROUP BY dept_no ORDER BY EmployeeCount Desc Limit 1 )
AS s  ON j.dept_no = s.dept_no  limit 1) as j on k.dept_no = j.dept_no;
```

this is printing an output as expected .